# Google Oauth: Get Name and Email WITHOUT asking for full Google+ profile

Tags: google-oauth

Is it possible to get a user's name without asking them for their full Google+ Profile?

I'm using the default scope (email, profile) right now, and have the Contacts and the Google+ APIs enabled on the Google Console.

I'm developing an app for students, and the less information I can have, the better.

Comment: What scope are you using currently?

Comment: @fyrye good point! Just edited the question.